# iOS arm64 support

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode6, arm64

I'm developing my iOS game by using Unity 5.0.2 *(xcode version is 6.1.1)*. When i tried to send my game to Itunes, i get 64 bit support error.

I resolve this issue by setting Unity/PlayerSettings/Other Settings/Configuration/Scripting Backend to **IL2CPP** from **Mono(2.x)** *(as mentioned in unity forum)*. However, when i do so, other crucial problem appears i.e. my ipa file's size increases to 78mb when i use **IL2CPP** *(when i used Mono(2.x) it was 43mb)*. How can i decrease my file's size, anyone can help me?

Comment: The problem with IL2CPP is that it generates a build for both 32 and 64 bits. Maybe selecting one of the architecture will reduce the size. Also, they claim to have reduced the size. The message was from 03 June 2015. Dunno if it is already in a patch though.

Comment: Thanks, i've just seen the patch, i'll try it out.

Comment: Patch release Patch 5.0.2p4 indicates iOS/IL2CPP: Decrease IL2CPP memory usage by making metadata structures const.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are going to see a size increase in the IPA, since the binary now needs to have both an ARMv7 slice and an ARM64 slice. There isn't too much we can do about that.

For more information, you may want to have a look at this thread on the Unity forums:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-build-size-improvements.322079

We're consistently working to decrease the binary and overall package size with each release of Unity, so I would recommend updating to the latest patch release if we need smaller binary sizes.

From your end, the best options are to investigate the code and eliminate anything unused or unnecessary. Usually, this shows up in 3rd-party libraries used via assemblies that might not be actually used.